# TFS 2017 and Fiddler - authentication problems

Tags: authentication, http-headers, fiddler

I'm trying to access the TFS REST API via Fiddler requests. I have one instance of TFS upgraded to 2017 version. For this version Fiddler is unable to authenticate. The difference I do see with the same call made towards TFS 2015.3 is in the 401 Challenge response from TFS.
In case of TFS 2015.3 I can only see the following headers:

```
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
```

Meanwhile for the TFS 2017 there are multiple WWW-Authenticate entries:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer
WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="http://my.tfs.address:8080/tfs"
WWW-Authenticate: Negotiate
WWW-Authenticate: NTLM
```

Can anyone explain why the IE or Chrome are able to cope with this headers and perform the authentication, meanwhile Filler is not? Is there a way to authenticate with Fiddler in this case (a workaround)?

Also no matter the IIS settings in regards to authentication, WWW-Authenticate: Bearer is always added.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting Rules > Automatically Authenticate? Perhaps the target has Extended Protection / Channel Binding enabled?

Comment: Hi Eric, sure I did, otherwise it is not working not even for the TFS 2015. Extended protection is switched off in IIS.

Comment: When you have the `Automatically Authenticate` rule set, do you see an additional request being automatically issued by Fiddler in response to the `HTTP/401` response from the server? Alternatively, have you tried using a breakpoint to remove all of the `WWW-Authenticate` headers except for the NTLM one? (If that works, we can automate it).